# How can I multiply count in sql?

Tags: sql

I tried using the following query

```
Select cost + scost from
(Select count(order no) as cost 
From platter order where cost= cost*25*discountpercent) ,
(Select count(order no)as scost from schoolorder
Where scost=scost*25);
```

I'm learning SQL so plz don't mind

Comment: You tried and what happen...

Comment: `select cost+scost` it's not correct

Comment: How the two tables `platter order` and `schoolorder` relate to each other? Please post the two tables' structures, if possible some sample data from the two tables and the desired output, and the RDBMS you are using???

Comment: the related tables are as follows

Comment: PlatterOrder(orderNo, deliveryDate, deliveryTime, invoiced, isBulk, platterQuantity, discountPercent, clientNo)
SchoolOrder(orderNo, deliveryDate, deliveryTime, invoiced, taxExPercent,
clientNo)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT
   (cost + scost) as Total_Cost,
   ((cost + scost) * 25 * discountpercent) as Discounted_Cost,
   count(order_number) as Order_Count
FROM
   schoolorder
WHERE
   scost = scost * 25
```

Comment: the related tables are as follows
PlatterOrder(orderNo, deliveryDate, deliveryTime, invoiced, isBulk, platterQuantity, discountPercent, clientNo) SchoolOrder(orderNo, deliveryDate, deliveryTime, invoiced, taxExPercent, clientNo)

Comment: select ((normalcost*25*0.5)+(schoolcost*25)) as "projectedcost" from
 (select count(orderno) as normalcost from platterorder p),
 (select count(orderno) as schoolcost from schoolorder);

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
Create table #temp (cost as decimal(1,2), scost as decimal(1,2))

INSERT INTO #temp
(Select count(order no) as cost From platter order where cost= cost*25*discountpercent) ,
(Select count(order no)as scost from schoolorder
Where scost=scost*25);

Select cost + scost from #temp
```

If we are understanding you correctly you want to get the sum of cost and scost?

Also in SQL you cant have spaces in your names: platter order should be platterorder or [platter order] if you must use spaces.

Comment: The temp table is totally unnecessary and only slows down things.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name true, but by breaking it up and showing it differently I was hoping to spur more questioning and help him see another option. Remember in software development there is multiple approaches.